# How to determine value shift in text input?

Tags: javascript, html

When input's width is shorter than a value inside, only the beginning of the value is visible. By using arrow keys (left and right) we can move the caret to hidden part of the value. In that case the value is shifted inside the input so that a part of the value which surrounds the caret is visible.

I would like to determine for how many pixels from the initial position the visible part is shifted. Is there any easy way to get this value without spying on caret's position on every keyboard event?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `size` attribute of the `<input />` according to the length of the value of the element.

Something like this:

```js
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function(evt){
 this.setAttribute('size', evt.target.value.length)
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="email" size="5" id="input"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a limited space for the input and value can be much longer than its full width.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to determine the pixel length of a string (by approximation). But browsers differ in scrolling the text. EDGE scrolls about three characters, while Chrome only does one.

```js
function getPixelLengthOfString(element, string) {
  var tempNode = document.createElement("span");
  tempNode.innerHTML = string;
  tempNode.style.fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue("font-size");
  document.body.appendChild(tempNode);
  var stringPixelLength = tempNode.offsetWidth;
  document.body.removeChild(tempNode);
  return stringPixelLength;
}

console.log(getPixelLengthOfString(document.querySelector("input.length"), "wmj")); //approximate length of three characters
```

```css
input.length {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="length" value="this has a very long length" />
```

Comment: Computing the length of a string isn't a challenge here. What I need is the method to determine which part of a value is currently visible in the input. For instance, in you snippet the input displays _this has_ and the rest is hidden. You can move the caret inside the input with the right arrow key to see the rest of the value (e.g. display _very lon_), but then some part of that value is hidden on the left. What I need is the length of that hidden part of the value (in this example it would be _this has a _).

Comment: Well once you know the approximate length of the string and you have the visible area in pixels and caret position you can kind of guess it.

Comment: Caret position isn't enough to determine what part of the value is currently visible in the input.